# Cant refresh the shown JTable after inserts

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a problem. I'm pretty new to `Java` and at the moment i try to learn some basic stuff.

So i created a little `GUI` with a `Textfield` vor Input and a `Button` to fire a query to my Database with the query (that contain the Input as Variable).

I filled a `ResultSet` with the result of the query and want to display the result in a `JTable`.
I tryed it with this:

```
public class AppWindow extends JFrame {

    private ResultSet rs = null;

    JTextField  textfield_where_1;
    JTextField  textfield_where_2;

    JTable tabellenspass;

    JButton     button;


    public AppWindow() {
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.initWindow();

    protected void initWindow() 
    {
        // Instanzieren:
        textfield_where_1 = new JTextField();
        textfield_where_2 = new JTextField();
        tabellenspass = new JTable();


        button = new JButton("muh");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Abfrage();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

        // Positionen festlegen
        textfield_where_1.setBounds(5,10,400,25);

        tabellenspass.setBounds(5,40,400,100);
        button.setBounds(300,110,100,30);

        // Elemente dem Fenster hinzufügen:
        this.getContentPane().add(textfield_where_1);

        this.getContentPane().add(button);

        this.getContentPane().add(tabellenspass);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void Abfrage() throws Exception
    {
        // Eingabestrings holen
        String eingabe1 = textfield_where_1.getText();

        select_dies_das ausgabe = new select_dies_das();

        rs = ausgabe.select(eingabe1);
        Ausgabe_Tabelle(rs);


    }

    private void Ausgabe_Tabelle(ResultSet rs)
    {
         try
         {

                // Rows / Columns der Tabelle setzen

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
            // Tabellenmodel

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            tabellenspass.setModel(model);

            //model.fireTableRowsInserted(0, 5);
            int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            // Resultset Zeiger zurueck setzen
            rs.beforeFirst();    

            while (rs.next()) {

                Object[] row = new Object[columns];
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                    {  
                        row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
                    }

                    model.insertRow(rs.getRow() -1,row);
                   System.out.println("miau");
            }

           // tabellenspass.setModel(model);  
            tabellenspass.repaint();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
    }
```

With `Abfrage()` i get the filled resultset and with `Ausgabe_Tabelle()` I fill the `JTable`, but the shown Table wont change.

I create a row `Object[]` that i fill with the `Data` of a whole row, and this `Object` i insert into the `JTable`.

With `initWinodw()` I create the little GUI.

Can someone explain me why the table wont refresh after the inserts?

Comment: try "model.addRow" instead of "model.insertRow"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm thinking the problem is with your `TableModel` that is not correctly initializated, you need to use the `public DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames){...}` constructor for give it the `header` names :)

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null,new String[]{"Col1","Col2"});
```

Of course you need to add or remove columns to the `model` according to your needs, also the `rs.beforeFirst();` statement is unnecessary becouse you already are using a `while loop` that checks if the `ResultSet` has another row with the `next()` method of this `interface`, if you use this statement, also confirm that your `ResultSet` is scrollable or you will get an

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.
```

Better comment this line

```
//rs.beforeFirst();
```

Also you can change your `model.insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);` statement with this `model.addRow(row);`
I have tried your code and this is the result

[image]

Maybe you should consider adding the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane` for keep visible the `headers`, and set `layouts` to your design, something like this

```
setTitle("Test");
this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel data = new JPanel();
this.getContentPane().add(textfield_where_1);
this.getContentPane().add(data);
data.add(button);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabellenspass);
data.add(scroll);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
textfield_where_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 25));
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, i use the rs.beforefirst(); because i already did a print in the console after the query to check if there is a result. (was just a test for me, because as i said, i try to learn some basics ;D) 
Okay, i will try your stuff and hope it work for me too.

Comment: @user3793935 This is solved but please read the edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To notify `JTable` about changes use [`fireTableDataChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29):

> Notifies all listeners that all cell values in the table's rows may have changed.

Also you can try revalidate and repaint or [`resizeAndRepaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#resizeAndRepaint()):

```
tabellenspass.revalidate();
tabellenspass.repaint();
```

or

```
tabellenspass.resizeAndRepaint();
```

And check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955605/repaint-revalidate-invalidate-how-to-use-them) for further info...

Comment: Hi!
Uhm, i cant use it on a JTable, but on the model. But it still dosnt change anything ;(
(and btw the resultset is not empty or something, the row contains 213 columns filled with data over 5 rows)

Comment: Mhm wont work. 
Is maybe something wrong with the initWindow procedure?
Or am i maybe not using the right variable?