# Change TableModel structure

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

so the scenario is that I've got a JTable with a number of JComboBox's as cells. On the selection of an element of a JComboBox, there needs to be a change in the structure of the Table Model. I've also got an 'output table' below which listens to the selection of the JComboBox's and re-validates accordingly, because of this, I need to keep the model of the query table the same so that it can reuse the listener. How can I change the structure of the Table Model?

```
DefaultTableModel QueryTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(dropDownUserSelection, resultsListHeadings );     
queryTable.setModel(QueryTableModel);

JComboBox box = new JComboBox(boxModel);      
queryTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(box));
```

I apologize if I am asking a question which has already been asked elsewhere, but I've had a poke around and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: That's a little unclear.  By structure, I assume you want to add/remove columns?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response... Yes that's correct.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your combo, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), and your call `fireTableStructureChanged()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TableModel` has the responsibility for notifying the parent table (or anybody listening) of changes to the model.

The general events available are data changed, cell updated, row inserted/removed and structure changed.

The "structure changed" tells the parent table that the structure of the table model (the number of columns and/or column names and/or types has changed) and it should completely update itself.

There are a number of ways you could achieve this.  You could have the existing table model change it self accordingly and fire a "structure changed" event or you could construct a new table model and apply it to the `JTable`, depending on your needs.

Comment: +1 `setModel()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513), also fires the required event.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad 40 today, 40 today...I feel so old ;)

Comment: If I do setModel(), then the model changes, and the listener no longer listens because it's a different model. So is the only option to fire structure changed?

Comment: @JSmith _is the only option to fire structure changed_ no, use the DefaultTableModel api to update (f.i. setDataVector) and the model will fire as appropriate. Anyway, your setup smells fishy - best to show an SSCCE as already suggested. And while you are at it: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them :-)

Comment: Hi, your suggestion of setDataVector() worked a treat. Next time I will be more helpful by including an SSCCE and sticking to naming conventions. Thanks!