# JCombobox adjusting text based on true/false

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, boolean, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which is has values `No` & `Yes`. This is how I store it into database:

```
jdto.setPlacement("Yes".equals(comboPlace.getSelectedItem()));
```

then pass the `jdto` into my create method. Selecting yes gives value true. I am struggling to work in reverse logic now.

I want to be able to automatically fill combobox with `Yes or No` depending on true/false value from database.

atm I have the following

```
fieldPlace.setSelectedItem(jdto.getPlacement());
```

I tried if else statement with string but was unable to do so.

can someone demonstrate how to achieve this.

this is getPlacement()

```
public Boolean getPlacement() {
        return placement;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- add Item to the DefaultComboBoxModel, can be intialized automatically from proper array implemented in JComboBox API
- you can to use setSelectedItem or to hardcode setSelectedIndex

for example

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComboBoxBooleanModel {

    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;
    private Vector<Boolean> comboBoxItems;
    private JComboBox box;

    public ComboBoxBooleanModel() {
        comboBoxItems = new Vector<Boolean>();
        comboBoxItems.add(Boolean.TRUE);
        comboBoxItems.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        box = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(box);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                box.setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
        });
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1250, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (box.getSelectedItem() == (Boolean) false) {
                    box.setSelectedItem((Boolean) true);
                } else {
                    box.setSelectedItem((Boolean) false);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ComboBoxBooleanModel comboBoxModel = new ComboBoxBooleanModel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the booleans in the model, not their string representation - custom rendering of the items is the task of a ... custom renderer.

```
 public class BooleanListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

     public Component getListCellRendererComponent( ... Object value, ...) {
          if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) { 
             value = "Yes";
          } else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(value)) {
             value = "No";
          }
          return super.getListCellRendererComponent(... value....);   
     }
 }
```

Comment: ok, but the problem is that it is always coming back from sqlite as false despite it is being true. mine getter and setter methods are boolean and not string

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `JComboBox` model contains instances of `String`, so write an auxiliary method that translates:

```
public String getPlacementString() {
    if (getPlacement()) {
        return "Yes";
    } else {
        return "No";
    }
}
```

Then use that method to `setSelectedItem()`:

```
fieldPlace.setSelectedItem(jdto.getPlacementString());
```

Comment: Hi, I am saving it like 'jdto.setPlacement("Yes".equals(fieldPlace.getSelectedItem()));' and it sets true if i click yes, but on the retrieval side its always coming as false even if it is true

Comment: Are you committing the transaction? Does the database show the update?

Comment: slightly disappointed ... mapping of items to a visual representation is the task of a renderer, not some auxiliary method (except when the latter is used by the custom renderer :)

Comment: @kleopatra: Absolutely right; this is a hack/patch. +1 to your (better) approach; an `enum` makes a good combo model entry. for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513).