# Reload JinternalFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, reload, jinternalframe

I have a swing Application that Has Numerous JInternalFrames. One of these Loads data from the database at form Load. I need it such that iin an action Event, the JInternalFrames Reloads Completely To the same state it was at when it first Showed with the new Data from the Database. I have tried Several Options Like:

```
revalidate(), repaint(); updateUI()
```

but None of them is working.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object obj = ae.getSource();
        if (obj == btnAdd) {

                    try {
                  ..................
                  revalidate();
                 // repaint();
                  //updateUI();

                    } catch (Exception db) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, db,
                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
      }
    }
```

How Can I reload the Whole JInternalFrame without closing it first?

Comment: can you try calling internal frame's getContentPane().validate()

Comment: NOpe this does not work also. I tried .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `revalidate()` & `repaint()` is valid methods for `add, remove, modify(change sizing, properties not value)` a new `JComponent`(s) to the already visible GUI
2. `revalidate()` & `repaint()` could be last code lines after all changes to the visible Swing GUI are done,
3. `revalidate()` & `repaint()` haven't something with reload data from Database to the `JComponents` as value in already visible Swing GUI, then you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
4. use `Runnable#Thread` (required wrapp all output to the Swing GUI into `invokeLater`) or `SwingWorker`, there are interesting methods for your job `publish()`, `proccess()` and `done()`, and these methods will notify EDT by default

Comment: You have an example I can look at? Am New.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to *replacing* the view in your `JInternalFrame`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15659286/230513), *update* the corresponding model to which that view listens. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513), a `JInternalFrame` having a `JTable` could be given a different `TableModel`.