# How enable/disable calling tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) method of AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

The method `tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)` of `TableModelListener` is getting called whenever data is loaded into table from a CSV file. I don't want this to happen.

I want `tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)` of `TableModelListener` to be called only when table rows are added or when some cell data is updated manually.

Can Somebody tell me how this can be achieved?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the listener _must_ be notified, you can't and must not disable that call. The way to go is a listener implementation that is intelligent enough to detect when/if it should do anything with the notification. Chances are that you are doing something suboptimal in your model, consider posting a SSCCE demonstrating what you want to achieve and explain _why_ you want it

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to create a new `TableModel`, to which no `JTable` is listening.  Update the table using `setModel()`, which will generate a single `TableModelEvent`. A minimal complete example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513).

Alternatively, remove and restore the problematic `TableModelListener`.